# New PC freeze just a few seconds after the Windows 10 installation program starts

Tags: windows-10, memory, motherboard, power-supply, freeze

The **problem**: my new brand new PC freeze after a few seconds while loading Windows 10 x64 setup. When the motherboard logo shows up and the Windows spinner starts, then it freeze. Hard reset required, that is, holding the power button.

**Setup**:

- Corsair CX450M 80 Plus Bronze 450W
- MSI Mag Z390M Mortar
- Intel Core i5-9600K
- Corsair Vengeance LPX 16 GB (2 X 8 GB) DDR4 3200 MHz C16 XMP 2.0
- Samsung MZ-V7S250 970 EVO Plus SSD

**What I've tried so far**:

1. All cables disconnected except for ATX power, CPU power and case power switch
2. Without the M2 SSD
3. Another (working) PSU
4. A discrete graphic card
5. Three different (working) RAM brands, in different slots and configurations (single 8gb and 2 x 8gb)
6. Different installation medium (USB pen drive and Zalman virtual CD)
7. Different OS' (Windows 7 x64 setup, CentOS live DVD, Windows 10 x64)
8. Clear CMOS removing the battery for a few minutes and load BIOS optimized defaults
   9  In BIOS settings, Advanced -> Windows OS Configuration -> Windows 10 WHQL Support" to "UEFI"

**Is the motherboard or CPU faulty? Any clue? Thanks.**

Comment: If it's a new MB, it's possible it's faulty, but not likely - you should be able to boot to hardware diagnostics to test (usually found in the boot menu).  Did you also enable Secure Boot when you enabled UEFI, as both need to be enabled (IIRC) to install Windows.  Did you download the Windows install media via Microsoft's Windows Media Creator (google)?  If not, run media creator, select to install on another PC so it saves the install media in ISO format, then use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) to create a bootable USB from the ISO.  If that doesn't work, it's likely a hardware issue.

Comment: Secure boot is enabled. Yes, I used Rufus to make the usb media and it works on another pc...

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure everything is wired up correctly inside, make sure the CPU isn't loose or try checking if something is breaking the connection between it and the motherboard. It does sound like an issue with the CPU or the Motherboard. You say disconnected your SSD just wondering what your alternative to that was? If it was a Samgung branded hard drive I've heard of people having all sorts of issues but I don't know too much about that to give you an accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It was the BIOS. Original BIOS was released around January 2019 and doesn't support i5-9600K. Updating the BIOS to 7C00v15 (2019-08-14) solved the problem.